# Overloading Array Allocation Operator

Tags: c++

Is there a way to overload the operator for allocation during object declaration?

Say we have this struct

```
template< int iArrayIndex > struct vector_t
{
    float flData[ iArrayIndex ];
};
```

Is there anyway to make it so when we initialize an object of this struct, the allocator for an array is actually overloaded to do something else?

```
vector_t vec[ 3 /*actually iArrayIndex, doesn't make 3 vector_t objects*/ ];
```

Comment: Why? Because `vector_t<3> vec;` does what you want and includes no surprises for anyone else looking at your code.

Comment: `T name[x]` creates an array, there is not much you can do about it.

Comment: You mean something like using a class member new overload? `void* operator new[]( std::size_t count );`

Comment: overloading the new operator will work! :D